# Vaadin application: handle application closing event

Tags: java, portlet, vaadin

I have a portal with different available portlets. My `Activity` portlet has some background threads which must be stopped when the portlet is unloaded (for example, when selecting another portlet). The Activity portlet is of class `GenericPortletApplication`, which implements the following interfaces:

```
import com.vaadin.Application;
import com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.PortletApplicationContext2;

public abstract class GenericPortletApplication extends Application implements PortletApplicationContext2.PortletListener {
...
}
```

I would like to know which method I can overload to make sure I will handle the closing of the application properly. I have tried `destroy` but this is not implemented.

The interfaces are defined [here](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/Application.html) and [here](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/terminal/gwt/server/PortletApplicationContext2.html) but I can not find the method which will be called when the application is unloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Vaadin the Application.close() is the method that is invoked when an application session is closed. Remember that is bound to session, not the whole application.

Comment: I have seen that method, but the documentation is not very clear. I am not sure whether I can *handle* there the closing event, or *I must call* close to make sure the application session is closed. From what you say, I gather it is the former.

Comment: Yes, you can programmatically close the application by calling that, but the close is called by the framework when session end, so that is also a way to handle the event. See: http://dev.vaadin.com/browser/svn/versions/6.7/src/com/vaadin/terminal/gwt/server/AbstractApplicationPortlet.java#L823

Comment: I have tested that, and it is indeed triggering, but just when *signing out* of the portal (I am using vaadin + liferay). What I need is an event which is triggered each time the portlet "looses focus" (I do not know the right term for this event)

Comment: I realize I have described my problem with confusing terms. I am neither looking for the "unload" event nor the "close" event, nor the "destroy" event, but for the "loose focus" event.

Answer (score 3):

I have managed to achieve what I think you were trying to do. Here is the code I used:

```
JavaScript.getCurrent().addFunction("closeMyApplication", new JavaScriptFunction() {
                     @Override
                     public void call(JSONArray arguments)
                             throws JSONException {
                         // call close method
                         close();                        
                     }


              });

        Page.getCurrent().getJavaScript().execute("window.onbeforeunload = function (e) { var e = e || window.event; closeMyApplication(); return; };");
```

Answer (score 1):

Please note that Google Chrome and Opera are triggering onbeforeunload, but not onunload whenever a mailto link is pressed. Therefore we do a browser check before:

```
final com.vaadin.server.WebBrowser webBrowser = Page.getCurrent().getWebBrowser();
if (webBrowser.isChrome() || webBrowser.isOpera()) {
    javascript.execute("window.onunload = function (e) { var e = e || window.event; closeMyApplication(); return; };");
} else {
    javascript.execute("window.onbeforeunload = function (e) { var e = e || window.event; closeMyApplication(); return; };");
}
```